# Deploying and Running Node.js app in Cloud

Tags: node.js, express, iis, amazon-ec2

I have a Mean stack node.js application and amazons remote desktop machine. I need to deploy my node.js application to amozon.

I have uploaded my files to wwwRoot folder. It contains a default index.html page.
After uploading files also, i got that same index.html display in browser.

Please let me know how i can deploy and run my node.js application.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you follow a guide or tutorial to get yourself set up with a node.js web server. From your question is seems to me that you're missing some key points on how a node.js web server functions and there's really not a single answer to your question. I recommend you read up on the following tutorial:

https://blog.risingstack.com/your-first-node-js-http-server/

Good luck!